# How to sum the values of fields?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have structs like this

```
  {
        "actionName": "add_new_paint_layer",
        "countUse": 1,
        "sources": "smth"
    },
    {
        "actionName": "clear",
        "countUse": 1,
        "sources": "smth"
    },
   {
        "actionName": "clear",
        "countUse": 5,
        "sources": "smth"
    },
```

How to sum "countUse" for actionName "clear"?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/ and http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Pipe

Comment: Where is your code showing your attempt? What didn't work when you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match:
    {'actionName': 'clear'},
  {$group:
     {_id: "$actionName",
     total_count:{ $sum: "$countUse"}}}
])
```

Comment: It is answer for my question. I have problems with understanding mongo, this simple answer have helped me.